# How to remove all a href tags from text

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a script to replace a word in a "ahref" tag. However i want to remove the a href entirely, so that you have the word Google without a link.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Hello <a href="http://google.com">Google</a></p>')
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    a['href'] = a['href'].replace("google", "mysite")
result = str(soup)
```

Also can you find all the words placed in a href and place a " " before and after them. I'm not sure how to. I guess this is done before the replacing.

Comment: Are you okay with leaving a pointless `<a>` in? You can just `del a['href']`.

Answer (score 17):

Use `del a['href']` instead, just like you would on a plain dictionary:

```py
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Hello <a href="http://google.com">Google</a></p>')
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    del a['href']
```

gives you:

```py
>>> print str(soup)
<p>Hello <a>Google</a></p>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to get rid of the `<a>` tags altogether, you can use the `.replaceWithChildren()` method:

```py
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Hello <a href="http://google.com">Google</a></p>')
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    a.replaceWithChildren()
```

gives you:

```py
>>> print str(soup)
<p>Hello Google</p>
```

...and, what you requested in the comment (*wrap the text content of the tag with spaces*), can be achieved with:

```py
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Hello <a href="http://google.com">Google</a></p>')
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    del a['href']
    a.setString(' %s ' % a.text)
```

gives you:

```py
>>> print str(soup)
<p>Hello <a> Google </a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks but will the Google i see be a link or normal text. Also how can i place a space before the google or any word in a href. Thanks

Comment: 1) I don't know from the back of my head how browsers render `<a>` tags without `href`—why not just try and see for yourself instead of having me do the checking? 2) I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: yup checked no links. Once i get all the "<a>" i want to place a " " right after the <a> and befor the </a>. So <a href ="somthing">Hello</a>. Should become, <a> Hello </a>

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: AFAIK,  `find_all` is now preferred over `findAll` (the latter available for backward compatibility).

Answer (score 7):

You can use bleach

```
pip install bleach
```

then use it like this...

```
import bleach
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href = "somesite.com">hello world</a>')
clean = bleach.clean(soup,tags[],strip=True)
```

This results in...

```
>>> print clean
u'hello world'
```

[here](http://bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) are the docs for bleach.